# How to restrict user to fetch only specific length video from the iPhone PhotoLibrary

Tags: uiimagepickercontroller, video-capture

I am working on an iOS application. In my application I have a screen in which user can add video and can share that added video to somewhere like FB and this purpose allowing user to add video in two ways user can add video

1. Shoot the new video from the Camera
2. Add the video from the iPhone library

I restrict to the user to don't add video more than the specific length say **60 sec**, for this purpose have used the `videoMaximumDuration` property of `UIImagePickerController`shooting time this property works properly, as the video reach to the maximum duration an alert popups and restrict to the user to shoot video more than that length.

But as in fetching the video from the library that property does not restrict to the user to show video less than or equal to that length.

How can I restrict the user so that he could not fetch the video which is more than a specific length?

Answer (score 0):

Use the delegate method imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: to check the picked video. Should it be too long provide a message to the user and return to the picker.